# Ignore first item in li

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create a function that lists the li class="table" items and this is what i got so far.

```
function getGuests(){
 $('.child').each(function () {
  $(this).find("li").each(function () {
    var guest = $(this).html();
    alert(guest);
  });
 });
}

<ul class="main">
<input type="button" class="addTable" value="Add Table">
 <li class="table">
   <ul class="child">
     <li class="header">Table 1<input type="button" class="addGuest" value="Add Guest" ></li>
     <li class="guest">example1</li>
     <li class="guest">example2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

It reads the li class="header" though, i is there a way to ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way in jQuery is this:

```
$(this).find("li:not(.header)").each(function () {
     var guest = $(this).html();
alert(guest);
```

http://jsperf.com/complex-selection-js-vs-jq/3

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [not filter](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(this).find("li").not('.header')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `:gt` selector:

```
 $(this).find("li:gt(0)").each(function () {
   var guest = $(this).html();
   alert(guest);
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bpZw9/)**

Comment: out of curiosity whats :gt ? first ive heard of.

Comment: Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/.`Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.`

Answer (score 1):

Use this function.

```
function getGuests(){
 $('.child').each(function () {
  $(this).find("li").not('.header').each(function () {
    var guest = $(this).html();
    alert(guest);
  });
 });
}
```